# How to restore deleted WEBSITE_CONTENTSHARE config value in Azure Function App

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-function-app

I have created an Azure Function App on Azure's consumption plan.  Being on a consumption plan, the configuration setting WEBSITE_CONTENTSHARE is required.  However, it looks like someone has deleted this value.  (It is typically of the form "my-function-name-suffix", where "suffix" is some string value).

How do I find the actual share location in Azure, in order that I might restore this value to the configuration settings?

Comment: Try browsing to your Azure Files.  There should be shared folders and you can see which of those relevant to your site.   If you are curious, the suffix was generated using hash(sitename, slot).

Comment: Hi, if my answer helps you, can you mark it as the answer of the question?:) [Link about how to mark answer](https://0730bowmanwindow.blob.core.windows.net/work/mark.png)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**If you delete your WEBSITE_CONTENTSHARE config value like this:**

[image]

**Then you can go here to get the value:**

1. Go to the storage your function linked to.

[image]

2. And you can find what you want:(My function name is 'openapifunctionbowman')

[image]